# Python 3.7.0 and PyQt5.11.2: module 'PyQt5.uic' has no attribute 'loadUI'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using the following code trying to show my Qt window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUI('app.ui', self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_)
```

Unfortunately, I always receive the error

```
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.uic' has no attribute 'loadUI'
```

I have already checked whether I accidentally used Qt4 attributes, but could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be load.Ui, not load.UI.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for every mistake but didn't see this one!